# touch events aren't disabled in android webview

Tags: android, android-webview, android-touch-event

I'm trying to disable touch events on webview, this is what I did

```
webview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Log.info("webview", "onTouch is called");
        return true;
    }
});
```

I see log messages on touch events, so onTouch() definitely always returns true. However touch events are still propagated to web view (e.g., I can still scroll and interact with buttons/links on the html page in webview). Do I miss anything here? How can I debug/fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to add `android:clickable="false"` in your XML, that might be of some help too..

Comment: I did try to add webview.setClickable(false) together with the above code but it didn't work. I didn't include it in layout since I just want to disable touch events temporarily.

Comment: Try `WebView.setFocusable(false);`, it should do the trick

Comment: I just tried, it didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whats happening there but the following have to work

XML

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/web_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>
```

JAVA

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final WebView webView = new WebView(this);
        setContentView(webView);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());

        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

        webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    public class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        // Catch additional url loading
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```